# How to make my wrist muscle thicker but strong?

Tags: bodybuilding

When someone grabs my forearm, he/she can easily grasp it just with one hand. It is because my forearm muscle is not thick enough.

[image]

## Question

- What exercise is good to make my forearm (especially the wrist part and its vicinity) thicker or bigger but strong so it becomes difficult to be grasped?
- What food is good for it?

Comment: If your primary concern here is "a bad person might grab me by the wrist" then there are several martial arts with specific techniques to deal with exactly this situation (the first that comes to my mind is aikido but there are certainly others.)  Seeking help in one of those communities might be useful for you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm afraid that's purely genetic. The only "muscles" in that part of the wrist are the Pronator Quadratus, and they are so small, they'll never get noticably bigger.

If you want thicker wrists, I'm afraid you're going to have to gain a LOT of weight. Fat, specifically.

Also, just to squash your food question; there is no food that is good for growing a particular set of muscles.

[image]

Answer (score -5):

Play tennis and consume good carbs and more protein based food for gaining muscle. Check forearm exercises & work and rest on and off.