# Neck band rotation

Tags: muscle, strength, training, injury-prevention, neck

For a while I've been doing neck extensions,side bends,neck flexions,neck tucks and neck grip holds with bands and plates

Are neck rotations with resistance band good too ? I've seen football and rugby players do them.

Should I make them an option to do instead of some other of the exercise listed or add them to the routine as a core neck exercise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make my wrist muscle thicker but strong?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/33839/how-to-make-my-wrist-muscle-thicker-but-strong)

Comment: I wrote an answer to the question mentioned above which I think may answer some of what you're wondering. If not, you may want to rephrase the question into something that hasn't necessarily been covered.

Comment: completely edited it then

Comment: Then I withdraw my close vote.

Comment: Neck rotation comes mostly from the deep muscles of the spine, it won't result in significant neck size.